# Check whether any part of row X of csv is in any of the following 8 rows. If yes, move row X.

Tags: python, csv

My program randomizes the rows in my csv file. There are 120 rows with 5 columns. The first two columns each contain the name of an image. There are about 30 (out of 2 columns*120 rows=240) image names that repeat, once each. The repeat (second copy) of an image name isn't necessarily in the same column as the first one (it may be in column 1 OR 2), but it might be.

I need to have the program check whether each of the 2 images in each row (columns 1 and 2) is also in one of the following 8 rows. If it is, I need it to move the row with the second instance of the image to the end of the file. Then I need it to check again (because some images repeat twice), and if it finds ANOTHER repeat, I need it to put that second repeat row somewhere else in the file. Don't care where, just as long as it's not within 7 rows of the target row (the one being tested).

Comment: could you provide your current source code?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin, unfortunately. I'm new at this but this may be the only time I ever need to do it in my life (it's part of a project my colleagues gave up on, so now it's on me)